# Javascript native method throws unexpectedly exception

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, exception, vaadin

I am updating a vaadin project from `vaadin 6` version to `vaadin 7`. It contains some native Javascript methods which work well in the old version. However some of them throw an exception when they should be called. I am not acquainted enough to `Javascript` programming and therefore I am not able to identify the source of the error. In particular the method is:

```
 protected static native void addSthToImg()
    /*-{
        $wnd.$(document).ready(function() {
            var = $wnd.$;
            var('.settingswrapper > img').addClass("imgStartup");
            if (var('.settingswrapper > img').hasClass("imgStartup")) {
                console.log("imgStartup exist");
                var('.settingswrapper > img')
      .animate(null, 300, function() {
                    var('.settingswrapper > img').removeClass("imgStartup");
                    var('.settingswrapper > img').addClass("imagePopIn");

                });
            }
        });
    }-*/;
```

On the Console in Chrome I see the error stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Object [object global] has no method '$'
```

What could be a possible cause of the error and why is it working in the old version? Is a jar/library missing?

Comment: @arjacsoh Have you included `jquery.js` in your page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: How do I include jquery.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like jQuery alias `$` is not defined in the global scope (denoted by `$wnd`). Are you sure your page includes jQuery?

You should have something like `<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` (but pointing to the actual location of jquery.js in your project) in your HTML source. I don't know if Vaadin manages JavaScript libraries automatically, since I'm not familiar with the framework.

Comment: How can this be done? Has it with the project-structure to do?