# Include jquery.js and javascript.js in the page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, browser, vaadin

I am trying to include jquery.js and javascript.js files on my page, as proposed in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132077/javascript-native-method-throws-unexpectedly-exception#19132222) by passing it through the Servlet class like:

```
 response.getDocument().body().appendChild(new DataNode("<script src=\"" + themeUri
                + "/js/nativeinit.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>",""));

        response.getDocument().body().appendChild(new DataNode("<script src=\"" + themeUri
                + "/js/jquery.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>",""));
```

When I see the Console in Browser though I see the messages for both files:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http:8080/uri/js/nativeinit.js". myhost/:47

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http:8080/uri/js/jquery.min.js". myhost/:47
```

And then:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                     nativeinit.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                     jquery.min.js:1
```

What is wrong and it cannot read them as script? Why this strange message of unexpected token? What should I change/add?

**Update:**

I have also added in my web.xml file:

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

but problem with the same message remains. I am aware of the fact that `@Javascript` annotation is the recommended way in vaadin 7, but I think it should work as well on the common way. I do not set Content Type in Servlet Class. I can use there only the class `BootstrapPageRespone` from https://vaadin.com/api/ , which does not provide the methods from `ServletResponse`. Otherwise I would have set it also programatically.

Answer (score 0):

check this question: [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text) - maybe when browser requests your script, it gets answer from server as text/html. Check MIME type of your server response.

Comment: I have added the content-type : text/javascript in the MIME-TYPES in Tomcat Configuration but it did not solve the issue. Anyway, I have tried the same in another project and it works. Something is not going well with the way I define the files in the Servlet, I think.

Comment: ok,so now when your browser requests for ex. your /js/jquery.min.js, it gets answer with content-type: text/html set in header?

Comment: make sure, that you dont set content-type to text/html in servlet, that process requests to your scripts

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to use the `@Javascript` annotation, as discussed in [this article](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20a%20JavaScript%20component).